# Worklight 6.1 application does not start due to Derby database failure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, derby, worklight-server

I am using:

1. WL 6.1
2. Derby as database
3. WAS 7

What I have done:

1. Performed manual steps for creation 2 databases (with proper schemas)
2. Created 2 datasources and tested from WAS7 web admin console (all works fine)

[image: DB]
[image: DB sample content]

On WAS 7 startup I have error messages that WL application can not start

`[18.4.14 20.40.18:503 FET] 00000000 ResourceMgrIm I   WSVR0049I: Binding Worklight Database as jdbc/WorklightDS
[18.4.14 20.40.18:507 FET] 00000000 ResourceMgrIm I   WSVR0049I: Binding Worklight Reports Database as jdbc/WorklightReportsDS
...
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'rssBrokerDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rssBrokerDS' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklight-direct' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklight-direct' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: FWLSE0206E: The project /MyProject failed to initialize, because the project database schema for data source jdbc:derby:C:\ProgramData\IBM\Worklight\derby_1\WRKLGHT is from version N/A, which is not supported by the server from version 6.1.0.00.20131126-0630. Use the Worklight ant tasks to upgrade the project database schema. [project MyProject]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)`

[image: DB section]

Comment: Can you please upload the full log as well as your worklight.properties file for further investigation

Comment: I added DB section of worklight.properties. Basically it's not changed because DB accessed via JNDI lookup and no password/user ID is needed. The WAS log does not contain any additional info, just posted fragment is repeated multiple times.

Comment: I think WL may fail because it may derive DB schema name from DB user name. I can't be sure, because I'm  not a WL author.

Comment: Or, rephrase, how can I define explicitly schema name for WL database? Is it assumed to be defined explicitly?

Comment: If you don't issue a SET SCHEMA statement, the default schema is set to the username you use to connect to the database.

Comment: I was able to fix the exceptions by providing custom property 'name' in WAS DataSource equal to schema name.  The schema name actually can be different. For example, WL 6.1 DDL scripts define it as WRKSCHM, but WL 6.1 Info Center as WORKLIGHT.

Comment: @BaratSahdzijeu, please write this as an Answer so others could benefit from it(!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the exceptions by providing custom property 'name' in WAS DataSource equal to schema name. The schema name actually can be different. For example, WL 6.1 DDL scripts define it as WRKSCHM, but WL 6.1 Info Center as WORKLIGHT.

So, I preferred WORKLIGHT as schema name and re-run DDL scripts. After that I have added the 'name' custom property in **Resources > JDBC > Data sources > Worklight Database > Custom properties** as shown on the image.[image]